# Query regarding the customized powershell reboot script

Tags: powershell

All,

I have a PS Script (to be precise borrowed, I am not a programmer)
This script is to reboot systems with these options "restart now" "restart after 4 hours" and "restart after 8 hours". The issue is I cannot figure out how to include "minimize" option on the title bar, I don't want the end user to exit out of it, so someone custom designed the box, alas that removed everything from the title (no minimize, no exit).
Please may I request someone to lend a hand with this one? Thank in advance.

The script:

```
Function Create-GetSchedTime {
Param(
$SchedTime
)
$script:StartTime = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($TotalTime)
$RestartDate = ((get-date).AddSeconds($TotalTime)).AddMinutes(-1)
$RDate = (Get-Date $RestartDate -f 'dd.MM.yyyy') -replace "\.","/"
$RTime = Get-Date $RestartDate -f 'HH:mm'
&schtasks /delete /tn "Post Maintenance Restart" /f
&schtasks /create /sc once /tn "Post Maintenance Restart" /tr "'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' /c shutdown /r /t 400" /SD $RDate /ST $RTime /f
}
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "Microsoft.VisualBasic") | Out-Null
$Title = "Message IT service desk - Action required "
$Message = "Your computer has not been restarted since it was last patched. Please save all your work and make the appropriate selections below"
$Button1Text = "Restart now"
$Button2Text = "Postpone for 4 hours"
$Button3Text = "Postpone for 8 hours"
$Form = $null
$Button1 = $null
$Button2 = $null
$Label = $null
$TextBox = $null
$Result = $null
$timerUpdate = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer'
$TotalTime = 300 #in seconds
Create-GetSchedTime -SchedTime $TotalTime
$timerUpdate_Tick={
# Define countdown timer
[TimeSpan]$span = $script:StartTime - (Get-Date)
# Update the display
$hours = "{0:00}" -f $span.Hours
$mins = "{0:00}" -f $span.Minutes
$secs = "{0:00}" -f $span.Seconds
$labelTime.Text = "{0}:{1}:{2}" -f $hours, $mins, $secs
$timerUpdate.Start()
if ($span.TotalSeconds -le 0)
{
$timerUpdate.Stop()
&schtasks /delete /tn "Post Maintenance Restart" /f
shutdown /r /t 0
}
}
$Form_StoreValues_Closing=
{
#Store the control values
}

$Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
{
#Remove all event handlers from the controls
try
{
$Form.remove_Load($Form_Load)
$timerUpdate.remove_Tick($timerUpdate_Tick)
#$Form.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
$Form.remove_Closing($Form_StoreValues_Closing)
$Form.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
}
catch [Exception]
{ }
}

# Form
$Form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = $Title
$Form.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(450,210)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$Form.Topmost = $true
$Form.KeyPreview = $true
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $Formalse
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$Form.MaximizeBox = $Formalse
$Form.MinimizeBox = $Formalse
$Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("c:\Windows\System32\UserAccountControlSettings.exe")
$Form.Icon = $Icon

# Button One (Reboot/Shutdown Now)
$Button1 = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(95,25)
$Button1.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(10,135)
$Button1.Text = $Button1Text
$Button1.Font = 'Tahoma, 10pt'
$Button1.Add_Click({
&schtasks /delete /tn "Post Maintenance Restart" /f
shutdown /r /t 0
$Form.Close()
})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button1)
# Button Two (Postpone for 4 Hours)
$Button2 = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(138,25)
$Button2.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(105,135)
$Button2.Text = $Button2Text
$Button2.Font = 'Tahoma, 10pt'
$Button2.Add_Click({
$Button2.Enabled = $False
$timerUpdate.Stop()
$TotalTime = 14400
Create-GetSchedTime -SchedTime $TotalTime
$timerUpdate.add_Tick($timerUpdate_Tick)
$timerUpdate.Start()
})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button2)
# Button Three (Postpone for 8 Hours)
$Button3 = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button3.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(145,25)
$Button3.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(243,135)
$Button3.Text = $Button3Text
$Button3.Font = 'Tahoma, 10pt'
$Button3.Add_Click({
$Button3.Enabled = $False
$timerUpdate.Stop()
$TotalTime = 28800
Create-GetSchedTime -SchedTime $TotalTime
$timerUpdate.add_Tick($timerUpdate_Tick)
$timerUpdate.Start()
})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button3)

# Label
$Label = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(445,35)
$Label.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(10,15)
$Label.Text = $Message
$label.Font = 'Tahoma, 10pt'
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

# Label2
$Label2 = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(355,30)
$Label2.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size(10,100)
$Label2.Text = $Message2
$label2.Font = 'Tahoma, 10pt'
$Form.Controls.Add($Label2)

# labelTime
$labelTime = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$labelTime.AutoSize = $True
$labelTime.Font = 'Arial, 26pt, style=Bold'
$labelTime.Location = '120, 60'
$labelTime.Name = 'labelTime'
$labelTime.Size = '43, 15'
$labelTime.TextAlign = 'MiddleCenter'
$labelTime.ForeColor = '242, 103, 34'
$Form.Controls.Add($labelTime)

#Start the timer
$timerUpdate.add_Tick($timerUpdate_Tick)
$timerUpdate.Start()
# Show
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
#Clean up the control events
$Form.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
#Store the control values when form is closing
$Form.add_Closing($Form_StoreValues_Closing)
#Show the Form
$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Please read through how to ask a question and format the code

Comment: LesFerch - Thank you, yeah thats correct this was borrowed. However the question is how to I get that minimize option alone without the X option on the title? PS - I am not a programmer :-(

Answer (score 0):

See the version of this script posted here:

[Custom Restart Script](https://www.bitsdrive.com/windows-10/windows-custom-restart-for-workstations-in-an-enterprise-domain/)

It's derived from the same source code and has a disabled close button and a functioning minimize button. If you compare your version of the script with the version at that link, that will show you what key items need to be changed in order to disable the close button and enable the minimize button.

Here are the changes you need to make...

Old code:

```
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$Form.MinimizeBox = $Formalse
...
$Form.add_Closing($Form_StoreValues_Closing)
```

New code:

```
$Form.ControlBox = $True
$Form.MinimizeBox = $True
...
$Form.Add_Closing({$_.cancel = $True})
```

Please also note that all occurrences of "$Formalse" should be changed to "$False". That's a typo carried over from the original script. It works just fine with "$Formalse" (as it would with any undefined variable) but it simply reads better with "$False".

Comment: LesFerch - Thank you, yeah thats correct this was borrowed. However the question is how to I get that minimize option alone without the X option on the title? PS - I am not a programmer :-(

Comment: The X option in that custom script is disabled. So, yes, the X is there, but it does nothing.

Comment: LesFerch - thank you, but how do I enable the minimize alone without the X?

Comment: There is no simple way to have a minimize button without an X button. The script I pointed you to provides the correct functionality. The user can minimize, but cannot exit. If aesthetically that's not acceptable, you're looking at doing some advanced code. There are clues at the following link, but it's beyond my skill set to make it work in a PowerShell script: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/754e37bf-a4b2-416a-909a-93ec7fed1d52/window-with-only-minimize-button?forum=wpf

Comment: Another option, that is potentially easier to script (but also may not meet your aesthetic requirements) is to disable all of the system menus (i.e. no minimize, maximize, or exit) and then provide your own "Minimize" button within the dialog box.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It shows the changes you need to make to your copy of the script so that the user can minimize, but not close, the window.

Comment: LesFerch - Thank you this is exactly what I wanted :-)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Super User. If this answer, or any other one, solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.